# Why SSE event handler has this error net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 after running 241 seconds while using PHP server side code?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, server-sent-events

I am using SSE to push data all day without interrupting but after about 241 seconds my connection interrupts and google chrome creates a new connection with a new request. its while the firefox browser blocks the transfer after this 241 seconds without reconnecting.
[image: chorme intrupt]

I changed cash to no-cash and even I changed the PHP script run time to 10000 in my host but this problem is there yet.

its my client side .js:

```
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  var source = new EventSource("sses.php");
  source.onmessage= function(event) {

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
    
  };
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
 
}
```

server side .php:

```
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');  
$ok=hi;
 while(1){  
echo "data: {$ok}\n\n";

ob_flush();
flush();

sleep(1);
}
```

I'll be thank full if u can help me.

Comment: you're sending headers in each iteration? that doesn't sound correct at all

Comment: i try headers out and in while loop but they have no differences!

Comment: are there any errors in the server PHP logs?

Comment: no the log_error is empty

Comment: As I understood it's related to the Keep-Alive header that has timed-out and max usage that have to be adjusting using httpd.conf in apache or other methods.